# active admin sort a count of a has_many column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activeadmin

Using the Active Admin framework, I can add a 'users' column that totals the count for a particular 'club' by doing this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Club do
  index do
    column 'Users' do |club|
      club.users.count
    end
  end
end
```

Can I make this sortable somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a [counter cache column](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) on teh `User` model's `belongs_to :club`, and then make your index like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Club do
  index do
    column 'Users', sortable: :users_count do |club|
      club.users.count
    end
  end
end
```