# Ruby on Rails - Active Admin - Dealing with Custom Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Using Rails 4 and the latest Active Admin. I am trying to build an Active Admin index page for my `Submission` model. In short, it's a contest app where one submission has many scores. In the `Score` model, there is a field called `:total_score` where a judge inputs their score for that entry.

So naturally, to find the final score of the submission I need to average all children scores:

```
# In my Submission model
def calculate_final_score
  self.scores.average(:total_score)
end
```

Which then returns the averaged number. Naturally, I want to display this number in my Submission Active Admin index page. I use this code (it's a table-format index page):

```
column "Score", sortable: :calculate_final_score do |submission|
  submission.calculate_final_score
end
```

While it displays the value fine, it does not know how to sort this custom method. Like, if I tell it to sort by that column descending, it will order it 10.0, 6.0, 3.75, 8.0, 9.0, etc. How do I get it to sort properly?

Secondly, it also does not know how to filter this custom method column. I put in the code `filter :calculate_final_score` but it does not display that filter on the page at all. Is this a limitation of Active Admin or is there a way to make that filter work properly? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a duplicate of the following questions:

- [active admin sort a count of a has_many column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744609/active-admin-sort-a-count-of-a-has-many-column)
- [ActiveAdmin: sort by association count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924458/activeadmin-sort-by-association-count)

nevertheless, those questions don't have a real answer to what's happening in active_admin and why this stuff is not working.

the reason for this can be found in [`ActiveAdmin::OrderClause`](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/3fb7f03335b1ec5743c305f2c37103e2bfface97/lib/active_admin/order_clause.rb#L18-L24).

it only supports columns on the model and columns on associated models.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to remove that functionality for now and hope it'll work in the CSV export I guess. I did see at least one of those questions before but, you're right, that wasn't the most optimal solution.